# If $f(-x-f(0))=f(x)+f^2(0)+2xf(0)$ is it possible to find $f(0)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the functional equation $f(-x-f(0))=f(x)+f^2(0)+2xf(0)$ if we substitute $x=0$ we get $f(0)=f(-f(0))-f^2(0)$ but if we substitute $x=f(0)$ we get $f(-f(0))=f^2(0)+f(0)$, which is the same result. Can we then conclude that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: $f^2(0)$ is $f(f(0))$ or $(f(0))^2$?

Comment: It is $(f(0))^2$